# PHP --- Comparing arrays to output the number of differences

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I'm trying to compare the strings in two different arrays and output the number of differences between both arrays. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<?php
$names = ['Tina', 'Dana', 'Mike', 'Amy', 'Adam'];

$compare = ['Tina', 'Dean', 'Mel', 'Amy', 'Michael'];

function outputDifferences($array1, $array2){

    $pushedArray = [];

    $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

    // loop through the array
    for($i = 0; $i < count($result[$i]) -1; $i++){

        array_push($pushedArray, $result[$i]);

        $outcome = count($pushedArray);
    }

    return $outcome;
    var_dump($outcome);
}
outputDifferences($names, $compare);
```

Comment: Who says you're doing anything wrong? We can't know since you aren't telling us what output you're getting, or what output you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You demonstrate in your code that you are familiar with the `count()` function. Why not just use it to return the number you're looking for?

```
<?php
function outputDifferences($array1, $array2){
    $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
    return count($result);
}

$names = ['Tina', 'Dana', 'Mike', 'Amy', 'Adam'];    
$compare = ['Tina', 'Dean', 'Mel', 'Amy', 'Michael'];
echo outputDifferences($names, $compare);
```

As to why your original code isn't working, the documentation for `array_diff()` says it "returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays" and this includes their keys. In your example, element 0 is the same in both arrays, so there's no element 0. Your for loop is bound to fail. Use a `foreach` loop to loop through sparse (i.e. non-contiguous) arrays.

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah I just figured it out before seeing your comment. I appreciate it. I didn't realize that array_diff() returned as an array.

Comment: No thanks needed, just **upvote** _any answers_ you found helpful, and **mark accepted** the _one answer_ that best answered your question! This marks the question as "closed" and will give you reputation points. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers